# Workspace templates with TFS 2012

Tags: templates, tfs, workspace

I recently installed Team Explorer 2012 and the TFS 2012 Power Tools to access our upgraded tfs 2010, since i need the functionality of workspace templates. But it seems that the creation of workspace templates does not work. I created an empty workspace (Why can't i create a workspace template without having an existing workspace?) and tried to create a workspace template from that. I set all the paths to the projects on the server and the local ones too, but when i want to create a workspace from that template, all paths are removed and the template is empty. Am i doing something wrong? Does anyone managed to get this work?

Comment: Hm. After reinstalling everything it suddenly worked...